# why the data injected in template is only available if user is logged In? want all public

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, web-development-server

I am working on a **portfolio** website with an about page. The **models** are created on the **DB**, and the template tagging is working, **but just if user is authenticated in the admin page**. I've **extended** the user model to a **userprofile** one, to show the portfolio data stored on the DB -  obviously I want this to be **public** for everyone but I can't get it. Also I want to manage **all** the models related to the app **just** with the **superuser**,  as I have no need to create more users because **is a simple portfolio for one single user**.

[image: Example of the view]

CODE:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile/', null=True, blank=True)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} Portfolio ".format(self.user)


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """Create the UserProfile when a new User is saved"""
    if created:
        profile = UserProfile()
        profile.user = instance
        profile.save()


post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)

# ########################################################################################

from coltapp.models import Post, Comment, UserProfile
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView, ListView, DetailView,
                                  CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView)


class AboutView(ListView):

    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'coltapp/about.html'
    select_related = ('userprofile')

 # ########################################################################################


from coltapp import views
from django.conf.urls import url

#
#
app_name = 'coltapp'

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^about/$', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),


]

# ########################################################################################


<div class = "separator" >

    <p align = "center" > User: {{user.get_username}} < /p >

    <h3 align = "center" > Bio < /h3 >

    <p align = "center" > {{user.userprofile.bio}} < /p >
    <p align = "center" > {{user}} < /p >
    <p align = "center" > {{object.userprofile.bio}} < /p >


< / div >


# ########################################################################################
```

Pastebin:

https://pastebin.com/4XCi0M8Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you use `{{ user }}` by default django template.

Django's build in context processor supply `user` by default, and if not logged in, it returns `AnonymousUser` (check the django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#built-in-template-context-processors)

So if you use `{{ user }}` tag in template, it automatically shows user who logged in now in the browser - and it's always you in your browser, so you can see in your portfolio.

#### 1. pass your own user to context

If you want to use your own user and shows it to anyone, (not logged-in user) you can pass your own user object context to template.

#### 2. use your UserProfile objects list

Or you can simply use `object_list` from your `ListView`: your portfolio lists are all in `UserProfile` objects list, right?

If you have only one user - it's you - you can just simply looping your UserProfile objects in template.

Not using `{{ user }}` but use `{{ object_list }}` for looping

If you have more questions, please leave a comment.

#### Update

this is simple exapmle for pass your own model using context data

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class AboutView(ListView):

    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'coltapp/about.html'
    select_related = ('userprofile')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AboutView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # just filter your user by username, email, pk...
        my_user = User.objects.get(username="your_username")
        context[my_user] = my_user
        return context
```

then you can use `{{ my_user }}` in your template.

and with **second question**, I couldn't clearly understand your it but... `object_list` from your `AboutView` is your `UserProfile` model objects.

Django `ListView` automatically pass your model objects, and it use default name - `object_list`. It means `object_list` equals to `UserProfile.objects.all()`

So if you forloop in template by using `object_list`, your all `UserProfile` objects are looping. Isn't it clear?

> I recommend not using default `object_list`. Instead, you can use your own name by adding `context_object_name = "profiles"` in `AboutView`. Then you can use `profiles` in template instead of `object_list`. Django Class Based View is really easy, but it's little bit implicated. If you want to know how view-template process work, try using FBV

This is exmple using `context_object_name`

```
class AboutView(ListView):

    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'coltapp/about.html'
    context_object_name = 'profiles'
    select_related = ('userprofile')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AboutView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # just filter your user by username, email, pk...
        my_user = User.objects.get(username="your_username")
        context[my_user] = my_user
        return context
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the message, can you please give an example of step one? **pass your own user context** .. and about you said in number two, yes my portfolio list is in UserProfile and I only have one user, My User. i am gonna follow your answer and check anyway, i just read the docs in your link, but if you can give me a snippet code i will be thankful (even more)

Comment: I have tried the looping solution, and it work because I only have one model only in a relation from the Django user with the userProfile, so good, but what if I want to access directly to this user profile or any **object** doing something like: {{ object_list.portfolio }}, or {{ objectt_list.carousel }} ?

Comment: I will edit my answer adding pass your own user context. But I can't understand second commend... what do you mean "access directly" and what's "{{ object_list.carousel }}"?

Comment: I found useful info reading the docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/   , and following your instructions, I will accept your answer anyway because it helps to guide myself to the fixing! gonna update with an answer to my post

Comment: i haven't seen your update, exactly that is what I did, implementing the get_context_data method, and with context_object_name, i can hit the DB and get exactly what i wanted, thank you very much !!! you are the best :)

Comment: It's good to hear solving problem! Also I recommend this site: https://ccbv.co.uk/ - you can see all Class Based View and their attributes. Happy coding!

Comment: sorry if I am bothering too much, just have the last question, how can I inject this context into the base.html, instead of about page? in that way, i could have this info on the whole site with the extend base.html @seuling

Comment: With a Context processor, found it ! and did it ! thank you by the way :D

Comment: You solve problem? Good to hear that! How did you fix it? I can suggest custom template tags or adding context processor! check django documents!

Comment: Yes, i did use a context processor function getting the data in the db, now i can use it around thr diferents area of the web site! That was the solution! Thanks a lot for guiding me to the knowledge!!! Cheers!